# What is the best way to read Bhagavad-Gita for new person?

Tags: bhagavad-gita

I purchased Gita two years ago. I started reading Bhagavad-Gita many times. But every time I'm stuck and start from beginning. Is there any recommended way to start reading gita ?

Comment: That sounds more like a motivation problem.

Comment: Connect yourself to question and situation of arjun